# standardize timezone in a large dataset

Tags: r

I have a large dataset corresponding to different sites and timezone.
I'd like to standardize all of the sites to "UCT". I'm struggling to transform the dates (which are a factor) to get the proper date format.

One small sample of my date looks like this:

```
       head(data_tz)
       site       DatetimeEnd         tzone
       FR01001   2014-10-28 00:00:00  UTC
       FR01001   2014-11-02 00:00:00  UTC
       FR01001   2014-01-20 00:00:00  UTC
       FR01001   2014-11-01 00:00:00  UTC
       FR01001   2014-01-13 00:00:00  UTC
       FR01001   2014-09-17 00:00:00  UTC
       ..........
```

This is a large dataset with 4 different tzone:

```
        unique(data_tz$tzone)
        "UTC"  "UTC-04" "UTC+04" "UTC-03"
```

And DatetimeEnd is a factor, which I need to convert to POSIXct, and then each site to "UTC". I have been trying different approaches but neither of them worked.
I am using:

```
newdata$DatetimeEnd <- as.POSIXct(data_tz$DatetimeEnd, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz=data_tz$tzone)
```

But I got:

```
Error in strptime(x, format, tz = tz) : invalid 'tz' value
```

And the same when using:

```
newdata$DatetimeEnd <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data_tz$DatetimeEnd, 
                    format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz=data_tz$tzone))
```

If I use:

```
newdata$DatetimeEnd <- as.POSIXct(data_tz$DatetimeEnd, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC +01")
```

It works, but it is not what I want, since there are some columns (sites) with "UCT +02"..(different tzone)

How can I use here the tz as an argument to get the right timezone? Any idea/suggestion would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use purrr::map2 to iterate over the rows of the columns DatetimeEnd and tzone, creating a new vector.